# How do I get a derived method to change one of its base variables or objects and then call the changed object from outside the class?

Tags: c#, variables, methods, radix, derived

I'm trying to change a variable/property declared only in the base class through a derived method. The result always gathers the assignment from the base declaration however.

The value is assigned false in the base and I am attempting to switch it to true in a derived method. When I call the derived variable from outside the classes though, it returns as false. I already tried altering the variable using the derived class as a generic parameter, but no luck.

```
public class CPlayer : Hybrid
    {
        public TextBox inputTBox { get; set; }

        public CPlayer(TextBox InputTBox) : base(InputTBox)
        {
            inputTBox = InputTBox;
        }

        public void initiateStats()
        {
            proteinMeterMax = 125;
            proteinMeterCurrent = 125;
        }
    }

public class Hybrid
    {
        public TextBox inputTBox { get; set; }

        public bool stopOn = false;

        public Hybrid(TextBox InputTBox)
        {
            inputTBox = InputTBox;
        }

        public void runResult<T>(T hy) where T : Hybrid
        {
            hy.stopOn = true; //Trying either format to be certain.
            stopOn = true;
        }
    }


CPlayer cy = new CPlayer(inputBox);    

public void doSomething() {
cy.runResult(cy);

    if (cy.stopOn) {
        //I want something to happen when this is true. But it keeps returning false.
    }

}
```

This value needs to be true so I can follow conditions outside the derived class. It keeps returning false though.

Comment: Is this your actual code? It seems to work just fine. Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It does? Well the code is only a snippet of the whole project. But I don't understand what I could be missing then. I'll need to get back on this after by shift until 12:00 EST.

Answer (score -1):

In my understanding, I think you want to override a property or method right. Then, you need to specify a keyword **virtual** to override a property or method from base class to derived class

For Example:

```
public class BaseClass
{
   public virtual bool stopOn {get;set;} = true;

   public virtual bool MethodName()
   {
       return stopOn;
   }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
   public override bool stopOn = false; // For property

   public override bool MethodName()  // For method
   {
       return stopOn;
   }
}
```

In my case you can change Base property value directly without overriding:

```
public class BaseClass
{
   public virtual bool stopOn {get;set;} = true;
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass(){
             stopOn = false;
    }
}
```

If you want to change methods/functions behavior in derived class you should need to override that.

Comment: That does not work at all. When making an override for the bool, I get an error message saying "The modifier 'override' is not valid for this item." It also tells me that it hides the inherited member unless I add 'new' to the modifiers.

Comment: I think you create a new property in derived class with same name of base class property name it will throw an error. If you want to override a property or method you need to mark that property as virutal in base class then only you can ..

public virtual bool stopOn {get;set;} // base class

public override bool stopOn { get { return base.stopOn; } set {base.stopOn = false;}} // derived class